# localhost take directory or path after /

Tags: url, gwt, localhost

As I am running the code in localhost mode and I have localhost:8080/url/hello. Is the value after / is the directory or the path Because I am getting the result as HTTP STATUS 404.

```
   public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event)
{

           String a=Window.Location.getHref();
           Window.alert(a);     
        if(Window.Location.getHash().equals("") || Window.Location.getHash().equals(null) || Window.Location.getHash()== null)
        {
            String SUBURL=a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("/")+1;
                String a1=SUBURL;
                Window.alert("LINK :: "+a1);

            if(!a1.isEmpty())
            {
                greetingService.shrturl(a1,new AsyncCallback<String>()
                  {

                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
                    {

                     Window.alert("fail");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String h) 
                    {
                        System.out.print("return value :: "+h);
                        if(h.equals(null))
                        {
                            Window.Location.replace("ERROR:PAGE NOT FOUND");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             Window.Location.replace(h);
                        }
                    }

                  }); 
            }
            else
            {
                new shorturl();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not exactly, this depends on how your web server is configured, say it can be a virtual directory, a symbolic link, a rewrite-rule-affected path, etc.

Comment: can you ellaborate about what you are saying

Comment: It is just a resource the http is making request to. It is whatever you want it to be. You can return a PDF when you get a request to /url/hello if you like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localhost: is telling the server to loop back on itself, so instead of sending a HTTP request to a forgien server to send it to a local server,

8080:, refers to the port number,

/url/hello/ refers to the directory structure within the local server

so yes if you are migrating your code from local to live then

```
http://localhost:8080/url/hello
```

will become

```
http://www.mywebsite.ie/url/hello
```

Comment: thanks,,can you clear my doubt as we are having www.tinyurl.com site they generate there tiny url from the long url.they have there domain and after / they store the long url in it .so its that the directory or they storing value in some other place.

Comment: TinyURL or any of those sites, make a hash up of your url, store the long url in there DB, and give you a short url that links to there DB and then redirects you to the original DB.. if you like my post can you mark it as helpfull, thanks

Comment: if I have to make that then what should I do

Comment: Waht are you trying to do exatly? you should put the generated URL in to an <a href="tinyurl">Tinyurl</a> tag and us it in your site, Im unclear as to exactly what you wish to achieve

Comment: yes through the href=tinyurl we can go to the link that I have stored in the DB but when that href is paste in the addressbar then that url should open which I have stored in DB.but I am not getting that.

Comment: I have stored the long and short link in my DB. and by clicking the short url and localhost give me the error HTTP STATUS 404.it means that it searching the directory that why this error is occuring.

Comment: did you create a hash map?

Comment: yes I have used the hash ie created history but its not working when the label is pasted in the addressbar

Comment: what language are you using? plain HTML and CSS, but what is powering your back end? J2EE , php?

Comment: I am using GWT(java) and on backend mysql

Comment: have you done a working test of a java hash map outside of the GWT envrionment, tested that you can get that working and then see if you can get it to work with GWT, then break it down to see if there is problems with your mysql calls

Comment: Im still unsure of what you are exactly trying to achive? are you trying to recreate the logic of tinyurl?

Comment: I want to create exactly the same working that the tiny url have

Comment: are you using any API's to do this ? have you seen this https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/

Comment: the functionality that to store the whole url after the / is being done by me as i have store the short and long url in the DB but when I paste that short url in address bar the long url does not open

Comment: I am not using any API but I want to achieve the same thing that your link is providing

Comment: Why dont you just use the google api if thats the case, you know reuse of code

Comment: but I donot want to use any API if any case the google server is done then my code will not run..can I make my own API like this

Comment: what do you mean to say